# This error occurred when closing the graph connection

Tags: mediapipe

when I use mutil-process calculator like this:
node {
calculator: "ut_test.MultiPacketOutputCalculator"
input_stream: "demo"
output_stream: "multi"
max_in_flight: 9
}

an error :
F20230612 13:43:46.781373 24124 calculator_context_manager.cc:73] Check failed: !mediapipe::ContainsKey(active_contexts_, input_timestamp) Multiple invocations with the same timestamps are not allowed with parallel execution, input_timestamp = Timestamp::Max()

how can i fix this

This error occurred when closing the graph connection